# Comma separated numeric values - PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How would I echo the numeric values as comma separated

```
foreach($report_value as $value):
    echo round($value['report_total_cost_usd'],2); // ex: 1,234,456.00                  
endforeach;
```

Comment: why my codes are not pasting ?

Comment: U need to put 4 spaces at the start of each row or highlight the code and press the code block button

Comment: Use `number_format` function for example

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_number_format  go through this link

Comment: State the question clearly

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL Solution**:

Use `format` function on the number with an input for decimal places.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select format( 1234456, 2 );
+----------------------+
| format( 1234456, 2 ) |
+----------------------+
| 1,234,456.00         |
+----------------------+
```

You can read the same as string from your scripting language and use.

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL: FORMAT(X,D[,locale])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

  - Formats the number X to a format like `'#,###,###.##'`, rounded to `D`
    decimal places, and returns the result as a `string`. If `D` is `0`, the
    result has no decimal point or fractional part.

Comment: @zzlalani: It seems, you made comment at wrong place!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for [number_format](http://php.net/number_format)

```
echo number_format($value['report_total_cost_usd'], 2, '.', ','); // ex: 1,234,456.00
```

Output

```
1,234,456.00
```

need some dedication towards the work, and some knowledge how to read manuals..

Comment: @krishna yes `$str = "1,234,456.00"` this is a `well formed numeric value`

Comment: oops...! sorry got the question wrongly, i thought his input string is with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
foreach($report_value as $value)
{
    echo number_format($value['report_total_cost_usd'],2,'.', ','); // ex: 1,234,456.00     
}
```

Comment: the output is `1,234,456` not `1,234,456.00`